# Split larger CSV file into multiple files based on the size in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've a CSV file which is of huge size and I want to split in into multiple files based on the size.

For example I've a CSV file with the name `TEST-REPORT-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV` which is of size 150MB

I want to split that file into multiple files by size which is 5MB. It means after the split we'll get 30 Files.

I need the output file name as `TEST-REPORT-[SEQUENCE]-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV`

SEQUENCE = 1,2,3,4,......

I've tried this `split -d -a3 -b 5M --additional-suffix=.csv sample.csv test_` and the split is working fine perfectly but only the first file contains the header(3 line) but I need it in all the files which are generated after the split

After the split we need to persist the header

Comment: Did get what exactly you're asking for @Renaud

Comment: You say that the output file name to be `TEST-REPORT-[SEQUENCE]-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV`. I don't see any code in your question where you would generate files of this name.

Comment: The output files are getting generated as testaa, testab, testac etc

Comment: If you type `man split` you will get the manual page for `split` and you'll see why you get `testaa, testab, testac`. If your `split` is the one from the GNU coreutils have a look at the `--additional-suffix` and `--numeric-suffixes` options. You can try `split -b 5m --additional-suffix=']-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV' --numeric-suffixes=1 TEST-REPORT-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV 'TEST-REPORT-['`

Comment: yeah seen that but I need a different output so need the community help

Comment: I would, after splitting, loop over the alphabetically sorted list of `testXX` files, and rename them according to your descired naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` utility differs if you're using a BSD-based Unix (e.g., macOS) or the GNU tools version on Linux. You can quickly tell them apart by running `split --help`; the option is only supported by GNU's `split` and will throw an error otherwise. Neither version supports the kind of naming scheme you want, they will always generate a "sequence" marker using letters (e.g., aaa, aab, aac, etc.), and this will be included regardless of your prefix or suffix.

> And in the CSV File I've a header and trailer as well and in the files which we split need to persist the header and in the trailer the count needs to be updated

Both versions support a `-b 5m` switch for chunking the file into separate 5-megabyte files, but they do this irrespective of line endings. If you want to preserve whole lines, you'll have to split them accordingly with the line_count. If you have header and footer lines that you want to include, `split` does not support that kind of action. Simply put, that's not what it's *for*.

For an *approximate* per-file size with your CSV lines preserved, and as well a fixed header and a variable footer, you'll need to use a more comprehensive script to parse and distribute the files the way you want them to look. Bash is not the most efficient way to do this, but if you have a "guesstimate" for the average line length, you can make a rough calculation and aim for a fixed CSV lines per file instead of a raw bytesize number.

As an example: if your average line length is about 140 ascii characters, then

```
1024 bytes x 1024 x 5 = 5 megabytes
5 megabytes / 140 chars per line ≈ 37500 lines per file
```

With a target line length, you should then "preprocess" your target CSV file to clip the header line, and the footer line. Then split the result, and finally post-process each file into one named as you actually need.

Here's an example, based on a single-line header row and a multiple-line trailing footer, this script will chunk a CSV with avg. 140-char line lengths into 1mb files (adjust the target csv length accordingly).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

raw_file="${1}"
target_csv_length=7500

header="$(head -1 "$raw_file")"
footer_lines=3
footer="$(tail -$footer_lines "$raw_file")"

# Automating the readout of the trailing lines to produce a template is not recommended. Use `%d` for the count of lines or sequence number; if there are any `%` signs in the footer change these to `%%` to preserve them below.
footer_template='This CSV file has %d lines.
Produced on Friday, '"$(date)"' 
Copyright (c) Foobar, Inc. 2021.'

# Same goes for your filenames:
filename_template='TEST-REPORT-[%03d]-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.CSV'

# Set up a scratch space for your files during processing
splitsville="$(mktemp -d)"
printf 'Wrote scratch directory: %s\n\n' "$splitsville"

# Now preprocess the CSV file and split it
footerless_length="$(( $(grep -cE . "$raw_file") - $footer_lines ))"
(
  cd "$splitsville"
  cat "$raw_file" \
  | head -$footerless_length \
  | tail +2 \
  | split -l $target_csv_length - raw.
)

# Now do the post-processing.
(
  cd "$splitsville" &&
  count=0
  for chunk in raw.*
  do
    chunk_len="$(grep -cE . "$chunk")" # grep is faster than wc
    csv_seq_filename="$(printf "$filename_template" "$count")"
    ((count++))

    printf '%s\n' "$header" > "$csv_seq_filename"
    cat "$chunk" >> "$csv_seq_filename"
    printf "$footer_template" "$chunk_len" >> "$csv_seq_filename"
    rm $chunk
  done
)
# Resulting files and sizes ...
du -hs "$splitsville"/*
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: @Ashok do you mean the script isn't running, it's throwing some error, or producing the wrong results? I don't have your data, so if you want help you'll need to be more specific.